# Прогресс бар по выполнению плана

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

Добого времени суток.
Есть задача.
К примеру есть сайт в который вносится информация о работе менеджера, например если сделал продажу то сумма и товар который продал.
Далее отображаем на сайте в процентах на сколько он выполнил работу.
Хотелось бы что бы отображалось в прогресс баре.
Какие есть библиотеки прогресс баров которые можно было бы связать с ларавелом и что бы прогресс бар наполнялся исходя из данных полученных из базы?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы лучше сначала определитесь кто у вас во фронтэнде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `HTML` есть тег `<progress min="0" max="100" value="50"></progress>`

### Демо

```js
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
const add = document.getElementById('add');
const subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  progress.value += 10;
});

subtract.addEventListener('click', function() {
  progress.value -= 10;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">

<progress class="progress is-success" id="progress" min="0" max="100" value="50">
</progress>

<div class="container">
  <button id="subtract" type="button" class="button is-danger">
    - 10
  </button>
  <button id="add" type="button" class="button is-success">
    + 10
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alexander Zaytsev, спасибо, то что нужно.